# Meteor Android SDK install Only said "Please follow the installation instructions in the mobile guide" although install of requirements

Tags: android, meteor

I've a problem while install android sdk using `meteor install-sdk` android command.The result is always

```
Please follow the installation instructions in the mobile guide:
http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites
```

I also did following step.

1. Install javasdk

   ricky@ricky-ubuntu:~/git/cdoctor/web_service$ javac -version
   javac 1.8.0_77
2. update environment:

   ricky@ricky-ubuntu:~/git/cdoctor/web_service$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
   /home/ricky/bin/Android/Sdk

   ricky@ricky-ubuntu:~/git/cdoctor/web_service$ echo $PATH
   /home/ricky/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/ricky/bin/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/ricky/bin/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/ricky/bin/Android/Sdk/build-tools:/home/ricky/bin/android-studio/bin
3. Install library:

   sudo apt-get install --yes lib32z1 lib32stdc++6
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree
   Reading state information... Done
   lib32z1 is already the newest version.
   lib32stdc++6 is already the newest version.
   The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
     libmemcached10
   Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded
4. Check KMV

   ricky@ricky-ubuntu:~/git/cdoctor/web_service$ egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo

   8
5. Check Android API 32 is selected.
6. And result always:

> ```
> ricky@ricky-ubuntu:~/git/cdoctor/web_service$ meteor install-sdk android
> Please follow the installation instructions in the mobile guide:
> http://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites
> ```

Someone or somebody please give me some advice, I took me 2 day after google many pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled on this question using Google but the provided answers didn't help. However, I finally figured it out. `meteor install-sdk android` does not install anything, according to [this forum](https://forums.meteor.com/t/cant-install-ios-sdk-on-meteorjs/16345) the command is deprecated by now. It only prints the instructions. Now you should write:

```
meteor add-platform android
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Install Android Studio. This will automatically install the SDK and needed components.
2) Open Android Studio
 * Go to “Settings”, or “Preferences” (Mac))))
 * Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK
3) Download the target you’re after.
4) Make sure ANDROID_HOME is set and tools and platform-tools are added to your command line path.
Here is what mine looks like on mac:

```
# Android
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/<me>/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Then try again following the provided instructions from Meteor.